# How are Mathematical Equality Operators Handled at the Machine-Code Level

Tags: machine-code

So I wanted to ask a rather existential question today, and it's one that I feel as though most programmers skip over and just accept as something that works, without really asking the question of "how" it works. The question is rather simple: how is the >= operator compiled down to machine code, and what does that machine code look like? Down at the very bottom, it must be a greater than test, mixed with an "is equal" test. But how is this actually implemented? Thinking about it seems rather paradoxical, because at the very bottom there cannot be a > or == test. There needs to be something else. I want to know what this is.

How do computers test for equality and greater than at the fundamental level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is no `>` or `==` test as such. Instead, the lowest level comparison in assembler works by [*binary subtraction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractor).
On x86, the opcode for integer comparisons is `CMP`. It is really *the one instruction* to rule them all. How it works is described for example in [80386 Programmer's reference manual](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/CMP.htm):

> `CMP` subtracts the second operand from the first but, unlike the `SUB` instruction, does not store the result; only the flags are changed.
>
> `CMP` is typically used in conjunction with conditional jumps and the `SETcc` instruction. (Refer to Appendix D for the list of signed and unsigned flag tests provided.) If an operand greater than one byte is compared to an immediate byte, the byte value is first sign-extended.

Basically, `CMP A, B` (In [*Intel operand ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax)) calculates `A - B`, and then *discards* the result. However, in an x86 [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit), arithmetic operations set condition flags inside the flag register of the CPU based on the result of the operation. The flags relevant to arithmetic operations are

```
Bit  Name   Function

 0   CF     Carry Flag -- Set on high-order bit carry or borrow; cleared
            otherwise.
 6   ZF     Zero Flag -- Set if result is zero; cleared otherwise.
 7   SF     Sign Flag -- Set equal to high-order bit of result (0 is
            positive, 1 if negative).
11   OF     Overflow Flag -- Set if result is too large a positive number
            or too small a negative number (excluding sign-bit) to fit in
            destination operand; cleared otherwise.
```

For example if the result of calculation is zero, the [Zero Flag `ZF`](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/appc.htm) is set. `CMP A, B` executes `A - B` and discards the result. The result of subtraction is 0 iff `A == B`. Thus the `ZF` will be set only when the operands are equal, cleared otherwise.

Carry flag `CF` would be set iff the *unsigned subtraction* would result in [*borrow*](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/basic-math/how-to-borrow-when-subtracting/), i.e. `A - B` would be `< 0` if `A` and `B` are considered *`unsigned`* numbers and `A < B`.

Sign flag is set whenever the MSB bit of the result is set. This means that the result as a signed number is considered negative in 2's complement. However, if you consider the 8-bit subtraction `01111111` (127) - `10000000` (-128), the result is `11111111`, which interpreted as a 8-bit signed 2's complement number is `-1`, even though `127 - (-128)` should be `255`. A signed integer overflow happened The sign flag alone doesn't alone tell which of the signed quantities was greater - the`OF` overflow flag tells whether a signed overflow happened in the previous arithmetic operation.

Now, depending on the place where this is used, a [Byte Set on Condition `SETcc`](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/SETcc.htm) or a [Jump if Condition is Met `Jcc`](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/Jcc.htm) instruction is used to decode the flags and act on them. If the boolean value is used to set a variable, then a clever compiler would use `SETcc`; `Jcc` would be a better match for an `if`...`else`.

Now, there are 2 choices for `>=`: either we want a signed comparison or an unsigned comparison.

```
int a, b;
bool r1, r2;
unsigned int c, d;
r1 = a >= b; // signed
r2 = c >= d; // unsigned
```

In Intel assembly the names of conditions for unsigned inequality use the words **above** and **below**; conditions for signed equality use the words **greater** and **less**. Thus, for `r2` the compiler could decide to use **Set on Above or Equal**, i.e. [`SETAE`](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/SETcc.htm), which sets the target byte to 1 if `(CF=0)`. For `r1` the result would be decoded by `SETGE` - Set Byte on Greater or Equal, which means `(SF=OF)` - i.e. the result of subtraction interpreted as a 2's complement is positive without overflow, or negative with overflow happening.

Finally an example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool gte_unsigned(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    return a >= b;
}
```

The resulting optimized code on x86-64 Linux is:

```
 cmp     edi, esi
 setae   al
 ret
```

Likewise for signed comparison

```
bool gte_signed(int a, int b) {
    return a >= b;
}
```

The resulting assembly is

```
 cmp     edi, esi
 setge   al
 ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple C function:

```
bool lt_or_eq(int a, int b)
{
    return (a <= b);
}
```

On x86-64, GCC compiles this to:

```
    .file   "lt_or_eq.c"
    .text
    .globl  lt_or_eq
    .type   lt_or_eq, @function
lt_or_eq:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    setle   %al
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   lt_or_eq, .-lt_or_eq
```

The important part is the `cmpl -8(%rbp), %eax; setle %al;` sequence. Basically, it's using the [`cmp`](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/cmp) instruction to compare the two arguments numerically, and set the state of the zero flag and the carry flag based on that comparison. It then uses [`setle`](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/setle) to decide whether to to set the **%al** register to `0` or `1`, depending on the state of those flags. The caller gets the return value from the **%al** register.

Comment: `SETLE` doesn't check the carry at all, instead it sets 1 on (ZF=1 and SF<>OF)

Answer (score 0):

First the computer needs to figure out the type of the data. In a language like C, this would be at compile time, python would dispatch to different type specific tests at run time. Assuming we are coming from a compiled language, and that we know the values that we are comparing are integers, The complier would make sure that the valuses are in registers and then issue:

```
SUBS  r1, r2 
BGE   @target
```

subtracting the registers, and then checking for zero/undflow. These instructions are built in operation on the CPU. (Which I'm assuming here is ARM-like there are many variations).

Comment: The compiler will use a non-destructive compare operation if there is one.