# Priority queue (Min Heap) ordering in Java

Tags: java, heap

I was working with the priority queue and came across this statement.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>((n1, n2) -> n1 - n2);
```

Functionally I know this is a min-heap, but can someone explain to me how `(n1, n2) -> n1 - n2` returns the smallest element?

Comment: Do not use that "comparison" function. It will break. See my comments on the selected answer. The first time somebody says, "this job must absolutely be the highest priority," and sets his item's priority to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the code is going to break. Replace that broken lambda with a real comparison function.

Comment: Thank you @JimMischel for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor accepts a `Comparator<? super E> comparator`.

Basically the statement `(n1, n2) -> n1 - n2` is just a shorthand for

```
Comparator<Integer> result = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer n1, Integer n2){
            return n1.compareTo(n2);
        }
    };

PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(result);
```

Comment: It's a *broken* comparison. If `n1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `n2` is any negative number, then the result of `n1 - n2` will be positive, indicating that `n1 > n2`. Any time `n1` is sufficiently small and `n2` is large enough, you will experience integer overflow and the comparison will break. **Subtraction is not comparison!**

Answer (score 5):

The question is already answered. I am just trying to add a simpler demonstration.

While using Comparator#compare, two integers are compared as following by the result of compare function.

```
 * Result is negative -> first element is smaller
 * Result is 0        -> they are same
 * Result is positive -> first element is greater
```

When you use `n1 - n2`:

```
* Result is negative -> n1 is smaller
* Result is 0        -> n1 and n2 are same
* Result is positive -> n1 is greater
```

When you use `n2 - n1`:

```
* Result is negative -> n2 is smaller
* Result is 0        -> n1 and n2 are same
* Result is positive -> n2 is greater
```

*Edit*

Following table is just to demonstrate that subtraction can be used for compare operations. If the operands and result does not fit into the datatype any operation will produce wrong result.

[image]

Comment: And if `n1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `n2 == 5` (or any positive integer), then `(n1-n2) >= 0`, due to integer overflow. Subtraction is not a substitute for comparison.

Comment: @JimMischel The pitfall you brought up here is not really a problem of using subtraction operation to compare values. Its a problem of using insufficient range of bits you need for your operation. Instead of Java if you use any dynamic language you will most likely never end up in the situation you mentioned.

Comment: It absolutely is a problem of using subtraction inappropriately. There is a "comparison" operator that is supposed to return the result of comparing two integers. But there are situations when it will return the wrong result, even when you pass it two integers. There is no situation in which that is correct behavior. And, yes, dynamic languages will (might?) do the right thing. I'd hate to base my mission-critical application on "mist likely". Anyway, the OP's question is about Java, not dynamic languages.

Comment: I could vaguely remember that in digital logic course we implemented comparator circuit by using subtraction operation. The operator you are referring to is basically translated into subtraction operation anyway, [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348278/1160106) and [Reference 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3kb07w/how_does_a_computer_compare_numbers_at_the_lowest/). Saying that, I totally understand the corner case you are pointing out. But my point was in general using subtraction to do comparison should be fine as long as you use proper type.

Answer (score 3):

That's a comparator that will be used by this PriorityQueue instance to compare the items. It should be the implementation of the `Comparator` interface but here it reduced to the so-called lambda expression `(n1, n2) -> n1 - n2`.

By the way, in your case it's better to use the predefined comparators like `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for this `PriorityQueue` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)):

> Creates a `PriorityQueue` with the default initial capacity and whose elements are ordered according to the specified comparator.

So you're passing a lambda which provides the `Comparator`. Looking at [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So in our case, if `n1` is smaller than `n2`, we will return a negative number, meaning that `n1` is less than `n2` and moving `n1` closer to the top of the heap.

If we wanted to reverse the sort order, we could just change the lambda to:

```
(n1, n2) -> n2 - n1
```